# How a thermodynamical system relaxes to equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, equilibrium

For a system in contact with a reservoir with well-defined constant temperature $T$, its change in Helmholtz energy satisfies the following inequality:

$$\Delta F \le -W_{by}$$

where $W_{by}$ denotes the work done *by* the system.

I know that in thermal equilibrium, Helmholtz energy of the system is minimized. But I don’t understand what the system is doing to minimize its free energy.

Based on the inequality, the maximum work that can be done by the system is $-\Delta F$. I am not sure if it indicates that the system *spontaneously* do work to decrease its free energy.

As the system approaches thermal equilibrium, its entropy increases $\Delta S>0$ until it reaches its maximum. I wonder if the system also increases its internal energy $\Delta U>0$, so that at equilibrium $\Delta F=\Delta U-T\Delta S=0$? If so, what are possible reasons for the system to increase its internal energy?

Answer (score 6):

What the equation $W\leq(-\Delta F)$ means is that, for all possible processes, both reversible and irreversible, between the same pair of initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states, subject to the constraint that all heat transfer takes place with an ideal constant temperature reservoir at the same temperature T as the initial (and final) states, the maximum amount of work that the system can do on the surroundings is the same for the subset of  all reversible paths and is equal to $-\Delta F$; all other paths are irreversible, and do less work on the surroundings.  The reversible paths are not spontaneous, and must be carefully controlled such that all changes along the path are quasi-static.

An example of this is expansion of an ideal gas in contact with an ideal constant temperature reservoir at the initial temperature of the gas.  The maximum work and decrease in F for a reversible path are $$W=-\Delta F=nRT\ln{(V_2/V_1)}$$The work for an irreversible path, say where we drop the pressure from the initial value $nRT/V_1$ to the final pressure $nRT/V_2$ and hold it at this final value for the entire expansion, the work is $$W=nRT\left[1-\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right]$$Mathematically, this is less than for the reversible path.

For a non-ideal gas, the internal energy can change even if the temperature is constant.  It can also change at constant temperature if there is a phase change or a chemical reaction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand what you mean by "reversible paths are not spontaneous." So all the work done by the system is not spontaneous? What triggers the system to do work? Also, how did you derive $W=nRT\left[1-\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right]
$?

Comment: A reversible process is constrained to do work very gradually in a highly controlled manner.  In a reversible expansion, for example, work can be done by very gradually removing pebbles from atop a piston situated in a vertical cylinder, at a sequence of increasing elevations.  This very gradually eases up on the gas pressure.  For the irreversible work W, the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston is constant at $nRT/V_2$, and the volume change is $V_2-V_1$, so the work is $W=\frac{nRT}{V_2}(V_2-V_1)$.

Comment: So based on what you wrote, $W=-\Delta F$ is the *maximum* possible work the system can perform on surroundings while it undergoes a *reversible* process where initial and final states are in  *thermal equilibrium*. But in thermal equilibrium, $F$ is already minimized. I don't see the point of the system doing further work to decrease its $F$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying,

Comment: I was thinking that $F$ measures the system’s capability to do any work on surroundings. Once $F$ is minimized which happens when the system reach thermal equilibrium with surroundings, the system cannot do any work because it doesn’t have any free energy left over. Yet you said that the inequality $W\le-\Delta F$ applies to any process where the system is in *thermal equilibrium* in initial and final states. So how can the system do further work on surroundings even though it’s $F$ is already minimized?

Comment: You are moving the system manually in the reversible case through a sequence of equilibrium states, or, in the irreversible case, throwing it out of equilibrium.  In the latter, when it reaches the final state, it does not change anymore.

Comment: Sorry, there is one more thing I don't understand. In the ideal gas expansion example you provided, can we say that the gas is in thermal equilibrium with the reservoir during the whole expansion process (ie. the gas is in thermal equilibrium before expansion, during expansion and after expansion ends)? Or the gas is in thermal equilibrium only after the expansion? Since the gas decreases its $F$ during expansion, it gets minimized when the expansion is done. Does thermal equilibrium happen when $F$ is minimized?

Comment: In the reversible expansion, the gas is in thermal equilibrium with the reservoir over the entire process.  In the irreversible expansion, the gas is in thermal equilibrium only before expansion and when the expansion ends; during the expansion, even though the gas temperature matches the reservoir temperature at the interface with the reservoir at all times, the gas temperature away from this interface is lower than the temperature at the interface, and the volume average gas temperature is less than the reservoir temperature..

Comment: Thanks, so in the reversible ideal gas expansion, $F$ is minimized and does not change since it is in thermal equilibrium with the reservoir during the whole process? In the irreversible ideal gas expansion, $F$ starts at a minimum. It increases then decreases during the expansion. After the expansion, $F$ returns to its minimum value?

Comment: Do you know how to determine the change in F between the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states of a system, say in the example I gave?

Comment: I am not sure because I am still fixated with the concept that "F gets minimized at thermal equilibrium." I really want to know how F changes between initial and final equilibrium states and how the minimum energy principle applies.

Comment: Well, it was already determined in my Answer.  Does it look from that equation like the change in F between the beginning and end of the reversible process was zero?

Comment: But doesn't it contradict the minimum energy principle?

Comment: Please precisely  state the minimum energy principle as you understand it.

Comment: I think I get it now... the minimum energy principle states that for a *non-isolated* system, a thermodynamic potential $\Phi$ tends to be minimized. A system is said to be in thermal equilibrium if and only if its temperature matches with the surroundings and $\Phi$ is minimized. For a system with constant volume $V$ and the number of particles $N$ in contact with a reservoir of constant uniform temperature $T$, the suitable potential in this case is Helmholtz energy $F$.

Comment: Between two states where a system is in thermal equilibrium with the reservoir, a system can do work on the surroundings as long as $W_{by}\le-\Delta F$ in any isothermal process. The maximum possible work that can be achieved by a system is the same as the work that can be done during any reversible isothermal process: $-\Delta F$. In a reversible (quasistatic) process, a system is in thermal equilibrium throughout the whole process, so its $F$ must constantly change to its new minimum value for each equilibrium state.

Comment: This means $F$ changes infinitesimally for each step in quasistatic process. I realized that my confusion came from the fact that thermodynamic potentials behave a bit differently from electric potentials or gravitational potentials. A thermodynamic potential does not limit how much work a system can do. In fact, it is free to do work. After it performs work, its state variables change and a thermodynamic potential adjusts itself to a new minimum value based on new state variables so that a system is in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: BTW, I think there is an issue in the example you provided. We are talking about the system in constant $T$,$V$, and $N$, so the gas should not do expansion work as it changes volume. Can you provide a different example? What kind of work the system can do under constant temperature $T$, volume $V$, and $N$.

Answer (score 5):

The minimization of free energy is a mathematical "invention" that formalizes the equilibrium state. The system does nothing to minimize its free energy, it can only respond to physical forces of various kinds that drive the system to equilibrium. These are capable of producing work. The Helmholtz energy is the maximum work that could be extracted from them as the system approaches equilibrium under the condition that temperature, volume and number of moles are all constant.

With respect to the last question:

> As the system approaches thermal equilibrium, its entropy increases $\Delta S>0$ until it reaches its maximum.  I wonder if the system also increases its internal energy $\Delta U>0$, so that at equilibrium $\Delta F=\Delta U-T\Delta S=0$? If so, what are possible reasons for the system to increase its internal energy?

There are several issues with the above statements that make it difficult to give a direct answer:

- It is not true that "$\Delta S>0$ until it reaches its maximum". This statement applies to an isolated system (constant $U$, $V$ and $N$) but here we are dealing with a system at constant $T$, $V$ and $N$.
- The correct equilibrium condition is
  $$ \Big(dF = dU - T dS = 0 \Big)_{T,V,N}$$
  Notice the differentials. For a spontaneous process $\Delta F$ is *negative*, not zero.
- By first law, $dU = dQ + dW$. Therefore, internal energy may increase or decrease, depending on the process that takes place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1. So the system cannot spontaneously work itself into its equilibrium state? What are examples of physical forces that drive the system to equilibrium? 2. I don't understand the meaning of "work that could be extracted." It refers to work by the system to the reservoir? 3. *For a spontaneous process $\Delta F$
 is positive, not zero.* I think you mean "For a spontaneous process $\Delta F$
 is negative, not zero"?

Comment: 1. The approach to equilibrium is always spontaneous. For pressure equilibration the force is due to the pressure difference between the two sides of a wall. In thermal equilibration it is the higher momentum of the molecules on the hotter side of the wall. 2. Think of a waterfall: work can be extracted from the tendency of the water to reach a lower potential energy. This work will not be extracted unless we place a suitable machine (turbine) in the path of the water. 3. Yes -- thanks for catching.

Answer (score 2):

The more general equation for dF is $$dF=-SdT-PdV+\sum{\mu_idn_i}$$where the $\mu$'s are chemical potentials.  The criterion for equilibrium of a closed system at constant temperature and volume is minimization of F (with respect to, say, chemical conversion):  $$dF=\sum{\mu_idn_i}=0$$